# Approximate Minimal Set Cover Python

Tags: python, set, cover

I have a list of lists each list contains the edge lengths of a polygon. For example:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1.1, 2],
 [0, 1.2, 2],
 [0, 1.3, 2],
 [4.5, 1.1],
 [4.4, 1.1],
 [5, 1, 2],
 [5, 1.1, 2],
 [5, 1.2, 2]
 [6, 1, 7, 4],
 [6, 1.1, 7, 4.1]]
```

I would like to be able to find a approx minimum "cover" in the sense that for each element of the "cover" all of it's values are within a specified tolerance of the elements it is covering. For example, if the tolerance is .1 given the list above I would like to get:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1.2, 2],
 [4, 1],
 [4.5, 1.1],
 [5, 1.1, 2],
 [6, 1, 7, 4],]
```

I am somewhat new to python so hopefully my use of terminology isn't too far off. Perhaps it would be helpful to explain my motivation.I am an architect trying to optimize a given surface panelization. Because of manufacturing tolerances panels with edges whose lengths differ by some fixed amount can be considered the same(in the example above all edges can differ by .1 and still be considered the same). I am trying to find a minimum set of panels that could be produced and still panelize the surface.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this problem? Keep in mind that this is not a code writing service.

Comment: You have a sublist `[4,1]`. This implies a two-sided polygon. Now I'm confused

Comment: Will all your final values be multiples of your tolerance value (or would you be willing to transform them so that they are)? If so, you could simply round off the values, then make a `set` to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: inpectorG4dget - I removed that sublist that you mentioned. The list I made was only to show an example of input and output and did not come from my dataset. the main reason for the [4,1] sublist was to show that the input values varied dimensionally. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Roger, yes. I have a solution but it is not a minimal list. my solution would give me [5,1,2] and [5,1.2] not [5,1.1,2]. I looked around and the problem seems similar to a geometric disk covering problem(except my disks would have to be balls of highest dim) regardless I don't understand the documents I have found regarding this problem

Answer (score 0):

To find an optimal solution here will be computationally quite difficult -- you seem to be asking for something, but it doesn't have to be perfect.

For the rest of this, I'm going to discuss a proposed algorithm for the 1D case, on the grounds that it's simpler to describe, but you can extend the algorithm to 3d.  I'm declaring a "range" to be [min,max].

For each point, do the following:
--Check the list of ranges to see if the point falls into one of them
----if it does, make that range now [max(min,point-interval), min(max,point+interval)].
----if it does not, add a new range [point-interval, point+interval]
Once complete, your output point list is the center of each range.

The idea here is to represent each point as the acceptable range it fits in.  Once you have that, any overlapping ranges can be reduced to their intersection, since anywhere in that intersection is acceptable to both initial points. This process can be continued until the ranges that remain do not overlap.